# Why postgresql can't been accessed after added Datadog agent?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

After added Datadog agent for postgresql, restarted Datadog. Reference:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/postgres/

Then check postgresql status, it's fine. But can't find in the process:

```
postgres@ip-1-2-3-4:~$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2018-06-18 06:21:05 UTC; 56s ago
  Process: 15863 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 15863 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 18 06:21:05 ip-1-2-3-4 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jun 18 06:21:05 ip-1-2-3-4 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
postgres@ip-1-2-3-4:~$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Also tried to restart postgresql:

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

The same result.

Comment: After upgrade PostgreSQL to 10, it works.